# Installing Windows Logitech drivers for Logitech Gaming Software on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, wine

I ran the official installer on Windows. I switched to Mint and I can easily open the LCore.exe with wine: `wine LCore.exe` It opens the software, but it's obviously just saying 'No devices detected'. I have a Logitech mouse (G700) and a Headset (G35).

Is it possible to install Windows drivers on Linux Mint, and if yes, how? There are some other exe files in the driver folder which I tried to run, but they only gave error message which I didn't understand, and also some .inf, .sys and lot of .dll files.

**[Here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4HAXofd3ZK_fjItQlhoaXhkVVlSLUF4dndUSkZCT2FRSFp2RmVoYmVRZlVHODhtS3IyNk0&usp=sharing)** are **all** the files which were installed.

I ran `wine DifxInstaller.exe` (the file is located in drivers/installers), which gave this output:

```
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation 0x230000 0 0x22fd50 4

DifxInstaller.exe <install|uninstall> <inf> [npnp=hardwareid] [flag flag ..]

Supported Flags:

 install:
      DRIVER_PACKAGE_FORCE
      DRIVER_PACKAGE_LEGACY_MODE
      DRIVER_PACKAGE_ONLY_IF_DEVICE_PRESENT
      DRIVER_PACKAGE_REPAIR 
      DRIVER_PACKAGE_SILENT 

 uninstall:
      DRIVER_PACKAGE_DELETE_FILES
      DRIVER_PACKAGE_FORCE
      DRIVER_PACKAGE_SILENT
```

After that, I ran `wine DifxInstaller.exe install DRIVER_PACKAGE_ONLY_IF_DEVICE_PRESENT`:

```
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation 0x230000 0 0x22fd50 4
fixme:difxapi:DriverPackageInstallA ("DRIVER_PACKAGE_ONLY_IF_DEVICE_PRESENT", 0, (nil), 0x140027550) stub
CDifxInstaller::DoInstall() returned 0
    Inf=DRIVER_PACKAGE_ONLY_IF_DEVICE_PRESENT
    Flags=0x0
CDifxInstaller::DoInstall(): reenumerating...
fixme:setupapi:CM_Locate_DevNodeA 0x22fa80 (null) 0x00000000: stub
```

Sadly, it didn't help, would probably be too easy. LCore.exe is still saying that no devices were found.

My system:
Linux asdf 3.16.0-38-generic #52~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 8 09:43:57 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wine [doesn't support USB yet](http://wiki.winehq.org/USB), and it also doesn't support installing device drivers. So no, you can't use it to install Logitech drivers for Windows on Linux.

On Linux systems most device drivers are already provided by the kernel, and nothing needs to be installed. If you're having trouble using your devices on Linux you can ask a new question with the relevant details.